# How can I get a UITableView's visible rect?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to detect if the user has scrolled to the bottom of a UITableView so that I can do some additional stuff. In order to calculate things properly, I need to get the UITableView's visible rect. How can I achieve this?

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{ 

    [_refreshHeaderView egoRefreshScrollViewDidScroll:scrollView];

    int currentMaxPosition = CGRectGetMaxY([self.tableView visibleRect]);
    int currentMinPosition = CGRectGetMinY([self.tableView visibleRect]);

    int tableViewBottom = [self.tableView bounds].size.height - 100;
    int tableViewTop = 0;

    //get older messages once we're near the bottom
    if (currentMaxPosition > tableViewBottom - 100)
    {
        NSLog(@"WE AT THE BOTTOM!");
    }      

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check in `[tableView visibleCells]` to get the visible cell or in `tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]` and determine if the user scrolled to the bottom.

Comment: Based on the visiblecell how do I determine if the user is at the bottom?

Comment: use `- (NSArray *)indexPathsForVisibleRows` to get index paths for these rows

Answer (score 22):

A UITableView is just a UIScrollView subclass, so all the usual UIScrollView methods apply, e.g. the visible rect of a UITableView is simply its bounds:

```
CGRect visibleRect = [myTableView bounds];
```

The origin of the visibleRect is simply the contentOffset, so another approach you can use is:

```
CGFloat distanceFromBottom = [self.tableView contentSize].height - [self.tableView contentOffset].y;
```

Comment: the distanceFromBottom is always 0 when I print it

Comment: Excellent. `-[UITableView bounds]` is perfect if for some reason one needs the visible rect of the tableview but not its full length (which would include invisible rows) content rect (in which case use `-[UITableView frame]`).

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to show an image when I tapped on a cell, and I wanted to find the frame to show it on (get the current position of the tableview).

I used the following and it worked:

```
//originalImageViewFrame is the CGRect that I use for my new view that I want to add to the view.
    originalImageViewFrame.origin = CGPointZero;
    originalImageViewFrame.size = self.tableView.contentSize;
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
    -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        int i=0;

        i=indexPath.row;

        int count=[urTablearray count];

        if (count == (++i)) {

                //do ur stuff here

        }


    }
```

Comment: that code doesn't compile, you can't modify a readonly attribute like indexPath.row.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load more cells when you reach the bottom try this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610299/scrolling-to-load-more-cells-in-uitableview-like-amazon-app).

Basically you know how many rows are currently in the table view, how many sections etc., use:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSections

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

You could also use:

```
- (NSArray *)indexPathsForVisibleRows
```

to figure out the index paths of the cells near the bottom..

Then use the following [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate) method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and use the `indexPath` value and compare it with "near" the bottom indexes. If near the bottom, do some action, like load more content.

Some apps have a dedicated "Load more..." cell to [manually load additional content](http://devblog.wm-innovations.com/2010/04/22/adding-a-load-more-cell-in-uitableview/). This approach is easier to get going, and it validates the 'loading more content' functionality in your app.